# How do you keep count of random numbers generated in an iteration function in Python?

Tags: python, random

So I have to create and iterative function that random produces shapes of different sizes after the user is prompted to enter the number of circles. I also need to keep track of the total radii after all the circles are drawn. I have set functions for the max of all the variables.

```
def drawBubbleIter(num):

    while num > 0:
        red = ...
        green = ...
        blue = ...
        color...
        begin_fill()
        circle(random.randint(1,MAX_RADIUS()))
        end_fill()
        up()
        rt(random.randint(-MAX_ANGLE(), MAX_ANGLE()))
        fd(random.randint(1, MAX_DISTANCE()))
        num = num -1
```

This creates random circles of shapes colors and moves at random distances and angles. How could I attempt to keep track of the radii?

Comment: What's going on here? http://stackoverflow.com/q/25878274/3001761

Comment: I guess this one uses a smaller turtle.

Comment: why is MAX_RADIUS a function though?

Comment: The MAX_RADIUS function is the max radius that any random circle could have so that there is a set range. It could easily be replaced by the number 20 but it is a requirement

Answer (score 1):

i think you want to store them in a list or something:

```
radii = []
while num > 0:
    r = random.randint(1,MAX_RADIUS())
    radii.append(r)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

How about putting the random radius into a list:

```
radii = []
while num > 0:
    ...
    r = random.randint(1,MAX_RADIUS())
    radii.append(r)
    circle(r)
    ...

print("the sum of all the radii is", sum(radii))
```

Comment: So I tried this but I keep getting an error stating that "name 'radii' is not defined"